# Dapper, XmlDocument and Cyrillic symbols

Tags: c#, mysql, xml, dapper, cyrillic

There are `XmlDocument`, `Dapper`, `MySql`, table's field `longtext` `utf8mb4` and connection `charset=utf8mb4`.

Using Dapper XmlDocument is inserted and selected from the database. It works fine if there are no cyrillic characters in the xml document. But if the xml document contains cyrillic characters, the document is not completely written, losing the characters at the end.

Is it a bug in dapper?
How to fix?

Comment: In my experience, it's more likely to be a bug in MySql.Data than Dapper. Try switching your MySQL ADO.NET library to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ to see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found sample code to reproduce your problem at https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/1303.

When I ran it with MySql.Data 8.0.17, the XML was truncated, as described. When I switched to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), the code worked as expected.

If you want to report a bug in MySql.Data (aka MySQL Connector/NET) and wait for a fix, the bug reporting site is https://bugs.mysql.com/.

Otherwise, I would recommend switching to [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/) as it is more stable and [fixes many Connector/NET bugs](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs).